# Why don't my cookies work properly in iframes?

Tags: php, cookies

here is my raw login page

http://wordswithfriends.net/mytourney/login.php

test user as follows:
l: testuser
p: test1234

Username displays here:

http://wordswithfriends.net/mytourney/test_cron.php

However if I wrap the above in an iframe as follows:

http://wordswithfriends.net/?page_id=386

Cookies don't seem to work.  To show this login using both with and without iframe.  Log out using iframe.

http://wordswithfriends.net/mytourney/test_cron.php

Still shows the username.  Log out using

http://wordswithfriends.net/mytourney/index.php

Which is exactly the same page.  Now the username disappears.  How can I get consistency between the two?

Comment: try specifying session save path with session_save_path() if that don't work, try specifying session cookie path and domain with session_set_cookie_params()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very subtle difference:

```
www.wordswithfriends.net (host: .wordswithfriends.net)

wordswithfriends.net (host: wordswithfriends.net)
```

Your cookies are clashing since the host domains are different. When you set the cookie, include the domain with a .domainname.net using [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

```
setcookie("cookiekey", $value, time()+3600, "/", ".wordswithfriends.net", 1);
```

(or however you do it)

And this will make sure it works for all domains, not just wordswithfriends.net.

**NOTE**

You might also want to adjust:

```
session_set_cookie_params(time()+3600, '/', ".wordswithfriends.net", true)
```

In case your session cookie needs to be adjusted too. [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Answer (score 1):

Your iframe has www.wordswithfriends.net as the domain, your page does not.  Try either using a wildcard cookie `*.wordswithfriends.net` or match the two domains.

Comment: Are you sure you need the *. for a wildcard? I've seen .domainname work.

Comment: You don't _need_ it, but I find it makes it easier to see.  A lonely period can get eye-skipped pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this hack](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/how-to-set-third-party-cookies-with-iframe.html) will help you because it seems to be a thirdparty cookie problem - but it's a kind of freaky a little bit...

Comment: It's not a third party cookie issue. They are both on the same domain.